# How do I access a nested menu item with AppleScript in Photos.app (to open each album in turn, to change sorting)?

Tags: applescript, photos.app

My end goal is to change all Photos.app albums under a certain folder to "Keep Sorted By Title" (View > Sort > Keep Sorted By Title).

It doesn't seem possible to directly set the sort order of an album via AppleScript (couldn't find it in the Dictionary, anyway).

So I figured I could have AppleScript open each album in turn, then change the sort order.

First step is to open each album in turn, which I thought I could do by clicking them in the View > Albums menu. But I haven't been able yet to figure out how to do that with AppleScript.

[image: screenshot]

This gets me the "Albums" menu:

```
tell application "Photos" to activate

tell application "System Events" to tell process "Photos"
    menu 1 of menu item "Albums" of menu "View" of menu bar item "View" of menu bar 1
end tell
```

Result:

```
menu "Albums" of menu item "Albums" of menu "View" of menu bar item "View" of menu bar 1 of application process "Photos" of application "System Events"
```

But I don't know how to get from there to say the "Hushings 2020" album.

For example, the result of `menu items of menu 1 of menu item "Albums" of menu "View" of menu bar item "View" of menu bar 1` is `{}`.

The result of `menus of menu item "Albums" of menu "View" of menu bar item "View" of menu bar 1` is just that single menu: `{menu "Albums" of menu item "Albums" …}`

The result of `entire contents of menu bar item "View" of menu bar 1` is a lot of data, but doesn't seem to contain anything from the submenu under "Albums".

How would I actually find the "Hushings 2020" album programmatically in this situation?

Alternatively, can I achieve my goal in another way? I saw someone mention elsewhere they bound a keyboard shortcut to "Keep Sorted By Title" and then manually clicked into each event and hit the shortcut. I'm open to that (it's just 600 albums or so) but I'd love to figure out how to do it programmatically via AppleScript instead – or at least to understand how to navigate these menus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Possible **AppleScript** solution:

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown below, was tested in **Script Editor** under **macOS Catalina** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate setting in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

---

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
tell application "Photos"
    activate
    set albumNames to name of albums
end tell

repeat with thisAlbum in albumNames
    tell application "Photos" to activate
    tell application "System Events"
        tell application process "Photos"
            tell menu bar item "View" of menu bar 1
                click
                click menu item "Albums" of menu 1
                click menu item thisAlbum of menu 1 of menu item "Albums" of menu 1
                click
                click menu item "Sort" of menu 1
                click menu item "Keep Sorted By Title" of menu 1 of menu item "Sort" of menu 1
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
    delay 0.5
end repeat
```

---

**Notes:**

In my **Photos** all of my entries under **My Albums** are a single level of **Albums**, so the *example* **AppleScript** *code* worked for me.

If you are trying to target **Albums** within a *folder* under e.g. **"Hushings 2020"** then:

**Change:**

```
set albumNames to name of albums
```

**To, e.g.,:**

```
set albumNames to name of albums of folder "Hushings 2020"
```

Note that because of the nature of how *menu items* are displayed in this case, the *album names* within the *folder* must be unique to the target *folder*.

You may need to add a `delay` *command* in-between the various `click` *events*.

Because of the *kludgy* nature of **UI Scripting** it is prone to issues/errors, and in this particular use case, once started you cannot do anything else on the computer and must allow the *script* to finish.

You could also break down the **Albums** into multiple *lists* and cycle thru a smaller number of *items* at a time, instead of trying to do all 600 at one time.

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

---

### Adding a *keyboard shortcut* for: **Keep Sorted By Title**

Go to **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **App Shortcuts** and press the **[+]** *button*.

For **Application:** select **[Photos]**.
For **Menu Title:** use **Keep Sorted By Title**
For **Keyboard Shortcut:** use: **⌥⌘T**

Then click the **Add** *button*.

[image]

You can then select one **Album** at a time and press **⌥⌘T** followed by a *down arrow* and so on.

Comment: Wow, this is amazingly thorough – thanks so much! So it seems like the piece of the puzzle I was missing is that one explicitly needs to "click" a menu item for the next level to be scriptable.

Comment: @Henrik N, RE: "So it seems like the piece of the puzzle I was missing is that one explicitly needs to "click" a menu item for the next level to be scriptable." --  Yes and no, it depends on the menu layout and in this case it's a yes because of the way **Photos** renders the menu in this particular area of its menu system.

Comment: Running this now – one small gotcha to be aware of: The screen saver may start while this script is running, and will abort the run. I used a free app (https://apps.apple.com/app/theine/id955848755) to keep the Mac awake. Turning off the screen saver presumably also works.

Comment: @Henrik N, RE: "one small gotcha to be aware of: The screen saver may start while this script is running, and will abort the run." --   I never use screen savers and when I'm going to do something I don't want interrupted by power management, I set it so the system stays awake. Thanks for the link. I'll check out the app.